# Javascript list filter - how to remove heading when filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code pen 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpXrjW?editors=1010 which is a simple Javascript filter taken from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

I was wondering what the easiest way would be to remove the headers from the filtered results, so if you search 'names' then none of the heading results show up as they currently do.

I thought writing a javascript function that says "on pressing of a key in the input box, change the style "display" to "none" would work:

```
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.."
title="Type in a name"  onkeypress = "hideHeaders()">


 function hideHeaders(){ 
    document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
   }
```

But this doesn't appear to yield any effect. Why does this not work, and what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `header` is not an id, but a class. You should select by class:

```
function hideHeaders() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".header").forEach(function(header) {
        header.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

Protip: Keep your indentation clean.

By the way, that will not make the headers return to their normal state when no key is pressed. If you have a code to hide it, you need a code to show it:

```
function hideHeaders(){ 
    setTimeout(function() {
        var empty= document.getElementById("myInput").value == "";
        document.querySelectorAll(".header").forEach(function(header) {
            header.style.display = empty?"block":"none";
        });
    }, 0);
}
```

The timeout is for the last keystroke to take effect, as the keypress event fires before the value is changed.

It checks if the input is empty and adds a `block` or `none` display style depending if the input has text or not.

Protip 2: When you code, always run your code with the Developer Tools opened (F12) in console tab. This way you will have noticed an error when your `getElementById` returns any value and you try to set the style of any value.

Comment: Works great :) is it possible to change it so that if there are no letters searched for (so if you search for something, then backspace so the search bar is empty with no letters), the headers reappear? Im guessing a simple if statement could work?

Comment: @SteveJobs That's the second part of the answer :P

Comment: @SteveJobs Yeah, onkeypress don't fires when you backspace. Just use onkeyup. Because there's already an onkeyup attribute, you should use the same attribute this way: `<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction();hideHeaders();" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">`

Comment: Edit: Thanks, only just saw the recent comment, accepting your answer :)

Comment: Could i just ask, what do you think would be the easiest way to create a 'No entries found' result if there are no list elements that match what is being searched?

Comment: @SteveJobs Inside the `myFunction` method that filters the elements, you can check if there's any (no header) element has is not hidden, then show/hide a message if it does or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138258/discussion-between-steve-jobs-and-jorge-fuentes-gonzalez).